# Assign reference of one Array to another Array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an Array like this:

```
self.shows = ko.observableArray();
self.shows([{showType: 'Morning', showTime: '11.30 A.M - 02.00 P.M', remainingCategories: '4'},
      {showType: 'Afternoon', showTime: '02.30 P.M - 05.00 P.M', remainingCategories: '4'},
      {showType: 'Evening', showTime: '05.30 P.M - 08.00 P.M', remainingCategories: '4'},
      {showType: 'Night', showTime: '08.30 P.M - 11.00 P.M', remainingCategories: '4'}]);
```

and another array like :

```
self.movies = ko.observableArray()
self.movies([{name: 'First Movie', shows: '4', remainingShows: self.shows},
   {name: 'Second Movie', shows: '4', remainingShows: self.shows},
   {name: 'Third Movie', shows: '4', remainingShows: self.shows},
   {name: 'Fourth Movie', shows: '4', remainingShows: self.shows}]);
```

Here I need to give a reference of `self.shows` array to `self.movies.remainingShows`, but the above code is not working...

In my HTML content I need to display the `length` of remaining shows. My code is like this:

```html
<span data-bind="with: chosenMovie">
    Only &nbsp;<span data-bind="text: remainingShows.length"></span>&nbsp; Show<span data-bind="visible: remainingShows.length > 1">s</span> Remaining.
</span>
```

This code is not okay: I am getting `length` as `0`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: is there any error message you can provide? what means not working?

Comment: `<span data-bind="with: chosenMovie">
     Only &nbsp;<span data-bind="text: remainingShows.length"></span>&nbsp; Show<span data-bind="visible: remainingShows.length > 1">s</span> Remaining.
    </span>`

I am not able to get `length` ... `chosenMovie` is defined as `self.chosenMovie = ko.observable();`

Comment: Hi infadelic.. If your not able to understand the previous comment please check the question .. I modified the question.

Comment: Providing `()` after `remainingShows` solved the issue . Finally `remainingShows().length` gives the `length`

Comment: Nice. Please consider also voting to close this as a duplicate then, so others can use your question to find that canonical one.